# Filtering a Crystal Report in code-behind won't show the first record?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have a custom Crystal Report Viewer, and one of the options lets users Filter by a Customer Code. The code-behind loops through the selected codes, and applies the specified filter to the report's `RecordSelectionFormula`

This works great on most machines, but I have one machine that doesn't show the 1st valid record in a filtered list. So if the user specifies they want to see only customer codes A, B, and C, it would pull all records where code is equal to B or C. If there is no record for A, then it won't show record B. The Totals on the bottom don't include the first record either, so it's not getting added to the report at all.

I can save the report as a .rpt file and load it into another machine that has Crystal Reports installed on it, and the data loads loads correctly when I refresh the report. The RecordSelectionFormula is correct: `{MySP;1.CustomerCode} in ['A','B','C']`

I'm really puzzled by this behavior. His machine is Windows XP, the same as our other machines. Both had the exact same install files run on them to install the .Net framework and the Crystal Report Viewer.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

For most of our Crystal Reports I've moved away from using the RecordSelectionFormula as much as possible. I've found that the Crystal Reports functions for viewing and selecting data worked very inconsistently and drove me nuts.

Is it possible to change the actual data pull to accept those parameters? All of my reports are pulling from SQL and my life got much less frustrating when I started doing all my data sorting and filtering using only SQL.

Comment: I'd rather not because it would require updating a lot of reports and their settings. The Report Viewer allows users to add any Crystal Report, specify which controls to display for required parameters, and which optional filters they want applied to the report. It allows users to add their own reports, instead of requiring me to go through and build every one. Its currently used with quite a few reports, and I'd have to go through each one and update the sql source, the report, and the report settings. In addition, then I'd have to build all reports >.<

Comment: What sort of problems did you encounter using the RecordSelectionFormula?

Comment: Ahhh - bigger than just a report viewer, then. The problems I ran into using RecordSelectionFormula were related to incorrect filtering and selection - I can't remember the exact situation, but I believe it was not filtering or selecting the same rows as if I put the identical logic in through SQL.